# onclick event get value from javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have this line

```
<td><a href="offer.php" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?key=' + getTableRow();return false;"><xsl:value-of select="product_name"/></a></td>
```

When i try to get the return value of the function getTableRow() and display it to href link i take key=undefined.Why happen that?

This is my script on the head of html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getTableRow() {
    var rowIdx;
    var rowData= [];
    var selectedRow;
     var rowCellValue;
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName || !document.createTextNode) return;
    var rows = document.getElementById('products_table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

          rows[i].onclick = function() {
          rowIdx = this.rowIndex;
              selectedRow= this.cells;
              for(j= 0;j<selectedRow.length;j++){
                rowCellValue= selectedRow[j].textContent ||
                selectedRow[j].innerText;
                rowData.push('cell '+j+': '+rowCellValue);
              }

          }
    }
    return "Row #" +rowIdx+'. '+ rowData[i];
}
</script>
```

I try many solution but nothing work..Please help..

In the beginning the only thing i want is to return the rowIndex.Even in that i get undefined.Why happend that?My first code before i try to get the content from row that user select.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userSelect;
function getTableRow() {
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName || !document.createTextNode) return;
    var rows = document.getElementById('products_table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

        rows[i].onclick = function() {
           userSelect = this.rowIndex;
            }
    }
    return userSelect;
}
</script>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish and what part isn't working?  Also, can you make a fiddle?

Comment: You're not returning anything inside `getTableRow`

Comment: Maybe you meant for the `return` line to be in `getTableRow()`, not the `onclick` function it binds to each row? Why would a click handler need to return a string?

Comment: Now you're referencing `rowData[i]` outside the `for(i...)` loop.

Comment: sorry i am new to javascript.I fix a little bit my code to understand and i post it again.This i try to accomplish is when a user click in one row of the html table to take the content of that row and attach it to the link href.

Comment: The content of that row i get it with the javascript function getTableRow().

Comment: I post the first thing i try to accomplish.Just to return the rowIndex.Even in that i get undefined.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably being caused

```
if (!document.getElementsByTagName || !document.createTextNode) return;
```

If you are getting undefined.

Best thing I can suggest is throw a load of debugging in e.g. :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getTableRow() {

    console.log( "getTableRow function called" );
    var rowIdx;
    var rowData= [];
    var selectedRow;
    var rowCellValue;

    if (!document.getElementsByTagName || !document.createTextNode) {
        console.log( document.getElementsByTagName, document.createTextNode, "Returning early" );
        return;
    }

    var rows = document.getElementById('products_table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

          rows[i].onclick = function() {
          rowIdx = this.rowIndex;
              selectedRow= this.cells;
              for(j= 0;j<selectedRow.length;j++){
                rowCellValue= selectedRow[j].textContent ||
                selectedRow[j].innerText;
                rowData.push('cell '+j+': '+rowCellValue);
              }

          }
    }
    console.log( "Returning correctly" );
    return "Row #" +rowIdx+'. '+ rowData[i];
}
</script>
```

If you're using firefox get yourself http://getfirebug.com/ and see what the console outputs

If you're using chrome press F12 and click on console and see what that says

If you're unsure about what's available in the document element try :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535862(v=vs.85).aspx

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp

Comment: There are no modern browsers where that `if` would succeed.

Comment: Yes i getting every time i try to do something to work undefined.You believe i must try to erase that line?Thanks

Comment: Try to just remove the  || !document.createTextNode

Comment: I try but not work.If i try to return 1 just for testing in the function getTableRow() work perfectly.But if i try to return the rowIndex not working.I put in my main post the first thing i try to accomplish before i try to get the content of the row.

Comment: You won't always see something wrong.

When you debug using a proper debugger you step over each line inspecting each object to see what's actually being set. 

In languages like Javascript there are tools to do this (firebug for one, you just need to set break points), but going through step by step outputting each variable is much easier to begin with.